# Discussion membership counter is not accurate

Tags: 2013, discussion-board, community-site, membership

The membership counter on our SharePoint 2013 discussion board is not accurately counting the numbers of people who have joined the board.

We think it may be related to the fact that the 'join the community' button has been deactivated. Is there a way to ensure that the counter is accurately reflecting the membership numbers even if the button has been deactivated?

Answer (score 0):

You can see my membership web part and leave this community section in page after clicked join this community button, if you able to see your membership counter will work as expected. sometime **refresh need to see updated count.**